# jQuery.Post/Ajax POST to PHP for writing XML file

Tags: php, jquery, xml, jquery-post

I have a client side code in jquery and from client side code I need to store some data on server side in form of XML files that are written using PHP. I'm done with the code for writing PHP files. However, I'm not able to pass client side code to PHP file. jQuery post is also not working. I tried query strings but as I said data is too large thus it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Thank you for your time and consideration.:)

Some Test Code:

### jQuery POST

```
$.post("test2.php", { userdata: "test"} );
```

### Ajax POST

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test2.php",
            data:   "userdata=" + "test" 
        });     
    });

});
```

---

PHP Code

```
$test = $_POST['userdata']; $document = new DOMDocument(); 
$document->load("collection.xml");
//Write XML file generation code
```

Comment: With post the data is send using headers, and therefore isn't as constrained due to size as the query string is, what errors are you getting with Firebug, are you trying to ajax to the exact same domain that your page exists on?

Comment: Show us some relevant code, please.

Comment: I tested using firebug but found no error. My sincere apologies for basic question but I'm newbie in this domain :(

Comment: your ajax code is correct except you are not handling response. better if you use $.post which can make your life easier see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/. Also please tell me how user data is collected at client end, is this a form or html contents?

Comment: Data is not a form/html content. I'm recording some data based on user activity in javascript variables (mainly in form of arrays) and sending this data to PHP

Comment: instead of array use objects and pass that object as it is in POST data to php.

Answer (score 1):

pass serializeArray() in case of form data. or create an array from the contents you want to send. for example

```
var sendingData = [];
sendingData = fillinData();
   OR
sendingData = $("form").serializeArray();
$.post("url.php", { xmlData: sendingData }, function(data){   });
```

loop through that data on server side for creating xml. You should use array so that no matter what is the size of contents it got wrapped up in a variable which can be fetched on server side.

[Convert js Array() to JSon object for use with JQuery .ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713884/convert-js-array-to-json-object-for-use-with-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it your problem is not receiving and writing out the data, but writing that data into a file stored on the server.  For this you need to use something like the php function fopen:

```
$handle = fopen("filename.xml", 'w');
fwrite($handle,$datafromclient);
fclose($handle);
```

I'm not sure why you want to write the data to files on the web server rather than store the information in a database but I'm sure you have your reasons.  Just be sure to consider the security implications and make sure people can't, for example, upload executable code and that permissions are set properly (and data is sanitised properly).

Good luck :)