# Sending two arrays using ajax post request

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am working on a filter functionality using ajax/jquery and php/mysql.I have two sets of check boxes **1)=>for Regions 2)=>for Localities**.The filter is similar to the one [here](http://www.proptiger.com/property-in-pune-real-estate.php). I want to send the values of both the check boxes to filter the records.The filter for localities will be locally filtered on the selection of a **region check box**.I have got it to work upto some extent
This is called on the first set of check boxes.

**Html**

```
<div class="locality">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" class="checkbox1" value="<?php echo $suburb['suburb_name']?>" name="Suburb_check[]" onClick="changeResults();" onChange="" ><?php echo $suburb['suburb_name']?>  <span class="grey">(<?php echo $suburb['total']?>)</span>
            </div>
            <?php }?>
```

**Javascript/Jquery**

```
function changeResults(){
    var data = { 'venue[]' : []};
        $("input:checked").each(function() {
            var chck1 = $(this).val();
            //alert(chck1);

                data['venue[]'].push($(this).val());

        });

    $.ajax({
     type : 'POST',
     url : 'process.php',
     data : data,
     success : function(data){


          $('#project_section').html(data); // replace the contents coming from php file

            }  
        });

   $.ajax({
     type : 'POST',
     url : 'loadLocality.php',
     data : data,

     success : function(data){
     document.getElementById("searchLoader").style.display = 'block';
              $('#localityList').html(data); // replace the contents coming from php file
        //   alert(data);
     document.getElementById("searchLoader").style.display = 'none'; 
            }  
        });  

    }
```

This is the second set of chck boxes with Localities

```
<div class="locality" id="localities">
            <input type="checkbox" onClick="changeLocality();" id="1" value="<?php echo $locality['locality_name'];?>" name="Locality_check[]"><?php echo $locality['locality_name'];?> <span class="grey">(<?php echo $locality['total'];?>)</span>
        </div>
```

I have called a function similar to the above one and posted it to a different page.
Here is the second chck box function:

```
function changeLocality(){
    var dataLocality = {'locality[]' : []};
        $("input:checked").each(function() {
            var chcklocal = $(this).val();
            //alert(chcklocal);
            dataLocality['locality[]'].push($(this).val());
        });

 $.ajax({
 type : 'POST',
 url : 'processLocality.php',
 data : dataLocality,
 success : function(dataLocality){
    // document.getElementById("newloader").style.display ="block";
          $('#project_section').html(dataLocality);        // replace the contents coming from php file
          //alert('data');
   // document.getElementById("newloader").style.display ="none";

        }  
    });

}
```

But,when I select a **region box and then a locality** box and then deselect the region,I also get the previous **locality** value in the region array(**name of the array is venue**)I want only regions to go in the venue array and **regions+localities in the locality array**.Actually,if I deselect the region subsequent locality value should also be removed from the array.Also,eventhough I am posting them to different pages the region page holds the locality values.I am stuck as not much of JQUERY knowledge.
Went through posts,but was not able to fix it.Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**
I get an array when I check the first set of chck boxes,and also filter the records using above functions.

```
Array
 (
    [venue] => Array
    (
        [0] => Pune East
        [1] => Pune West
        [2] => Pune North
        [3] => Pune South
    )
```

)

If I now click on any of the second set of chck boxes,I get an array of this sort.

```
 Array
 (
  [locality] => Array
    (
        [0] => Pune East
        [1] => Pune West        //[0] and [1] are regions
        [2] => Aundh
        [3] => Kalyaninagar     //[2] and [3] are localities
    )
```

)

**Note:** A region can have multiple localities.But I want both of them to be different arrays as they are two different parameters to the SQL query for filtering the data.
Hope I am clear enough now!  
**Is my approach RiGHT??Or can it be done in an easier way?**

Thanks

Comment: first check while passing as data:  { key : data }

Comment: Thanks Zuber,In my case that would be say, data:{locality:data},its a key value pair so the key can be any??Right??Also,how can i access on the php side???$_POST['name of the key']??Is it??

Comment: That gave me similar results!!
Also edited my question further! http://www.proptiger.com/property-in-pune-real-estate.php if you have a look here,you may get a idea what exactly i am trying.

Comment: @Learner Thank you for the edit.Any help would be appreciated too!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well now I think its a stupid mistake!! :P
The issue was with the names of the checkboxes. In Javascript we cannot have `venue[]` brackets[] in the name of the checkboxes.I presumed it to be similar to PHP for posting arrays.
Learnt it after some reading and search!!!Issue is resolved
Thanks to those who answered.

Answer (score 2):

you select the contents of an object using a `.` so your

```
data['venue[]'].push($(this).val());
```

should be:

```
data.venue[].push($(this).val());
```

Comment: Thanks @Christopher,this gives me a syntax error and my previous code works for that.i get the values and post it to the form.I get it in the array as a post.My problem is that I am not able to work with the 2nd check box.Please if you can have a look at this link and the fucntionality,you will get an idea of what exactly i am trying.
http://www.proptiger.com/property-in-pune-real-estate.php

Answer (score 2):

try changing

```
 $("input:checked").each(function() {
```

to

```
$("checkbox[name=check_box_name]:checked").each(function() {
```

change this for both, I hope this will work

Comment: I have tried this,still doesn't seem to work!!! `$("input[name=Locality_check[]]:checked").each(function() {   
   var chcklocal = $(this).val();
    //$(this).each(function(){
    alert(chcklocal);
    dataLocality['locality[]'].push($(this).val());
    //})
      });` Still both the arrays are mixed on the server side!!