# Error while sending array in array using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I am trying to pass an array in an array via ajax. If I do not pass in the additional array, it works just fine.

For example:

```
var settings = [];
// add stuff to the array

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "api/update-settings",
    data: {
        userId: 1,
        userSettings: settings
    },
    done: function(response) {
        //do something with the response
    },
    fail: function() {
        // do error stuff
    }
});
```

Sending this will not work. The API (in PHP) gets the code and is able to tell me what `userId` is, but `userSettings` is not defined.

> Notice: Undefined index: userSettings in /api/update-settings.php on
>   line 9

However, if I set the `settings` variable as a different data type (such as an int or string), the index is no longer undefined.

Within the PHP, when I dump request to see what's in it, `userSettings` is not found:

```
var_dump($_REQUEST);
Output: array(1) { ["userId"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

I'm adding items to my array using `settings['template'] = template;`

Before I submit the ajax request, I can console log it and I get this:

```
[p: "setting1", s: 1587, emp: "setting2", ems: 3245, template: "", …]
```

which contains all data that I need.

I tried to stringify the data with `JSON.stringify(settings)` but then ajax passes an empty array:

```
array(2) { ["userId"]=> string(1) "1" ["userSettings"]=> string(2) "[]" }
```

I feel like this is something simple, but I can't figure it out. And yes, I've done my searches - I've found similar things, but none of the responses seem to help.

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: Can you verify that you are actually sending all of the data via the network tab? Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/21617685/2191572 and find your "Request Headers". It's also possible that you are having cache issues or you are testing the completely wrong page.

Comment: Are you sure you're actually "adding stuff to the (`settings`) array"? Because if you're not, I'm pretty sure it won't send anything for an empty `userSettings` array in the request's body.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - Well, if I change the variable to NOT be an array, it sends, so I am assuming it's sending.

Comment: @Jeto Yes, I am sure. If I do a console.log I get the full array filled with the correct data.

Comment: @Jeto is correct anyways, jQuery will not send an empty array like that. You can verify by doing `var settings = [ 'yay something!' ];` instead

Comment: "I'm adding items to my array using settings['template'] = template;". So it's not an array, it's an object (on JS side). It should be declared with `var settings = {}`.

Comment: @Jeto My apologies... I thought that was an array. I had declared it using `var settings = []` as the post says. Changing the `[]` to `{}` makes it work. Thank you

Comment: @Jeto if you submit an answer with that correction I will make it as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the way you're adding values to your `settings` variable, what you want to manipulate/send is an object, not an array.

You need to change your declaration from:

```
var settings = [];
```

to:

```
var settings = {};
```

Comment: That's it. I knew it was something simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried serializing the array? You can find this approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713884/convert-js-array-to-json-object-for-use-with-jquery-ajax), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890524/pass-array-to-ajax-request-in-ajax) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery).

so it could end up like

```
var settings = [];
// add stuff to the array

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "api/update-settings",
    data: {
        userId: 1,
        userSettings: JSON.stringify(settings);//here is the change
    },
    done: function(response) {
        //do something with the response
    },
    fail: function() {
        // do error stuff
    }
});
```

hope this helps.

Comment: I tried that, too. It does send more, but only a blank array. I'll add this in my question